# Adding more fields in locator style to creat customized address locator

Tags: arcgis-10.2, geocoding

I have a database following the structure of "US Dual Range Addresses" and I want to, in addition of the fields used in dual range addresses, add more fields and I want to know what are the changes I have to make or the steps I should follow.

Comment: Can you please be more specific?  When you say you want to add more fields are you referring to City, State, Zip, etc?  Also is there a reason you are still using ArcGIS 10?  ArcGIS 10.2.1 is the current release.

Comment: Actually I am using ArcGIS 10.2, i am it was imposed by my final project manager. for more precision, I want to add fields, the fields I want to add are for example "region" it's used in our country to specify something that is bigger than a city, and smaller than a state. I just want to know how to add a field and what changes I must do in the "USAddress.lot.xml" to add the field to the style

Comment: As to my original question, when you say you want to add more fields are you referring to City, State, Zip, etc?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do use.  You are able to add additional fields in your search as well as an alternate names table.  You will see the bottom three options in the screencap below are for a right and left additional field and also a alternate name table join id.  This id field is used if you have table with alternate names (i.e. If a HWY is known as two different names).  I hope this is the information you were looking for.

[image]

Comment: Note that the Left Additional Field and Right Additional Field are just passed through to the output table - they aren't used in matching.  See [the 10.1 docs](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002500000013000000) for details.

Comment: thank you dbaston that is what I meant by adding field. I want to add fields to use them in the matching not just pass them through the output table. That was the reason why I asked the question.

Comment: @dbaston So you want to add additional fields to the dataset itself?